# Add HTTP message handler in .NET 6 REST Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have implemented a Message Handler (`DelegatingHandler`), here is my code:

```
public class BongLogClient : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var responseBody = task.Result.Content;
            var requestPath = request.RequestUri.LocalPath;

            LogToFile(responseBody, requestPath);

            return task.Result;

        });

        return response;
    }

    private void LogToFile(HttpContent body, string url)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"D:\temp\restbonglog.txt", DateTime.Now + " : " + url + Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(@"D:\temp\restbonglog.txt", DateTime.Now + " : " + body.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

    }
}
```

In my .NET 6 REST Service in the Program.cs file have added following code line:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
    {
        builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(builder.Services.GetRequiredService<BongLogClient>());
    });
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<BongLogClient>();
```

When I run the service the handler is not registered and I don't log anything to the file location.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here or show me to implement it correct in the service?

Comment: Have you read through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#outgoing-request-middleware)?

Comment: Hi Kirk, Yes i have also tried the implementation sample from MS doc link and it didn't work. There was one person who wrote that the handler class also need to be added to the ServiceCollection. Do you know how to add that or the code line.. I couldn't find a sample of how to do that.. I'm new to REST services

Comment: Can you include an example of how you get a `HttpClient` that you then use?

Comment: I'm not getting any HttpClient.. I run the service directly from the Visual Studio and uses swagger to test.